# how to make a double loop in xml with r

Tags: xml, r

I'm relatively new in r and xml, so there might be an obvious answer which I couldn't find.

I'm extracting information from an xml file and want to get data from nodes which have the same name, but belong to different parent notes which also have the same name. The structure is like this:

```
<CropSequenceClass>
  <nameCropSequenceClass>
    <Description> Name</Description>
    <Units>-</Units>
    <Name>nameCropSequenceClass</Name>
    <Value>1</Value>
  </nameCropSequenceClass>
  <CropClass>
    <name>
      <Description>Crop name</Description>
      <Units>-</Units>
      <Name>name</Name>
      <Value>Winter wheat3</Value>
    </name>
  </CropClass>
  <CropClass>
    <name>
      <Description>Crop name</Description>
      <Units>-</Units>
      <Name>name</Name>
      <Value>Winter wheat2</Value>
    </name>
  </CropClass>
</CropSequenceClass>
<CropSequenceClass>
  <nameCropSequenceClass>
    <Description> Name</Description>
    <Units>-</Units>
    <Name>nameCropSequenceClass</Name>
    <Value>2</Value>
  </nameCropSequenceClass>
  <CropClass>
    <name>
      <Description>Crop name</Description>
      <Units>-</Units>
      <Name>name</Name>
      <Value>Winter wheat4</Value>
    </name>
  </CropClass>
  <CropClass>
    <name>
      <Description>Crop name</Description>
      <Units>-</Units>
      <Name>name</Name>
      <Value>Winter wheat5</Value>
    </name>
  </CropClass>
</CropSequenceClass>
```

I can get all four of the 'CropClass' nodes with getNodeSet and loop through them, but I hit a wall when I try to split these nodes up according to their parent nodes.
I tried getting only the first 'CropClass' nodes into one nodeset by referring to the first 'CropSequenceClass' nodeset like this:

```
getNodeSet(doc, "//CropSequenceClass[1]/CropClass")
```

It worked, I got two nodes. 
The problem is that I'd like to loop through these 'CropSequenceClass' nodes to get all batches of 'CropClass' nodes (in this example 2+2), but if I try the code below it doesn't work:

```
k <- 1
getNodeSet(doc, "//CropSequenceClass[k]/CropClass")
```

I'd appreaciate any help, either with this syntax or as a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

You're pretty close. Try this:

```
n <- length(doc["//CropSequenceClass"])
result <- lapply(1:n,function(i)doc[sprintf("//CropSequenceClass[%s]/CropClass",i)])
class(result[[1]])
# [1] "XMLNodeSet"
```

So now `result` is a list of `XMLNodeSets`. `result[[1]]` has the `CropClass` nodes corresponding to the first `CropSequenceClass`, etc.